# Java UnZipping a zipped .app back to .app (OS X)

Tags: java, macos

In my auto updater application i am downloading a zipped file that contains the new MyApp.app application file. So i am downloading MyApp.zip.. Then i use this following class to try and unzip it:

```
package update;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class UnZip {

  public static final void copyInputStream(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
  throws IOException
  {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;

    while((len = in.read(buffer)) >= 0)
      out.write(buffer, 0, len);

    in.close();
    out.close();
  }

  public static final void unZipIt(String F1, String F2) {
    Enumeration entries;
    ZipFile zipFile;

    try {
      zipFile = new ZipFile(F1);

      entries = zipFile.entries();

      while(entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry)entries.nextElement();

        if(entry.isDirectory()) {
          // Assume directories are stored parents first then children.
          System.err.println("Extracting directory: " + entry.getName());
          // This is not robust, just for demonstration purposes.
          (new File(entry.getName())).mkdirs();
          continue;
        }

        System.err.println("Extracting file: " + entry.getName());
        copyInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(entry),
           new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(entry.getName())));
      }

      zipFile.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.err.println("Unhandled exception:");
      ioe.printStackTrace();
      return;
    }
  }

   }
```

However after the unzip the application wont launch.. any ideas?

Comment: did you make the unzipped file executable?

Comment: How would i do that? :)

Comment: Well should be said that before i zip it and send it to the server the file executes fine

Comment: in a terminal, `sudo chmod u+x /path/to/file` or similar

Comment: Have you tried computing a hash of the app before and after to ensure it has not been corrupted in some way? This would be the quickest way to tell you if the problem is because the program is corrupt versus a local system issue.

Comment: You probably do need to make it executable, but knowing more about mac app than @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, I suggest that you type:
`sudo chmod +x /path/to/app/MacOS/app`
instead. `app` must be replaced with what the actual file under `MacOS is named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your executable file is most likely not flagged as executable. The trick is that `.app` "files" are in fact directories, so making them executable serves no practical purpose, you need to find the actual binary.

To do that, you need to open `./myApp.app/Contents/Info.plit` and look for the `CFBundleExecutable` key: the associated string is the path of the executable file, relative to `./myApp.app/Contents/MacOS`, I believe.

Once you've found that file, `chmod +x` it, and check whether your application still fails to start.

If it doesn't, problem solved.

If it does, try and open your application from the terminal through the `open ./myApp.app` command. If anything odd is printed, update your question with it and let us know what that was.

If all else fails, look into the `Console` application for interesting log entries - you can search for your application's name, see if anything comes up.

Comment: This solved it! Thanks for helping me locate the error! http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81330/downloaded-apps-does-not-start-error-10658

Comment: Also some apps have bundled helper apps, whose executables you will have to also locate and make executable. It can be quite a pain.